# Single repository with generic methods ... bad idea?

Tags: nhibernate, generics, fluent-nhibernate, repository, repository-pattern

I'm currently trying out a few different ways of implementing repositories in the project I'm working on, and currently have a single repository with generic methods on it something like this:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    T GetSingle<T>(IQueryBase<T> query) where T : BaseEntity;

    IQueryable<T> GetList<T>(IQueryBase<T> query) where T : BaseEntity;

    T Get<T>(int id) where T : BaseEntity;

    int Save<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity;

    void DeleteSingle<T>(IQueryBase<T> query) where T : BaseEntity;

    void DeleteList<T>(IQueryBase<T> query) where T : BaseEntity;
}
```

That way I can just inject a single repository into a class and use it to get whatever I need.

(by the way, I'm using Fluent NHibernate as my ORM, with a session-per-web-request pattern, and injecting my repository using Structuremap)

This seems to work for me - the methods I've defined on this repository do everything I need. But in all my web searching, I haven't found other people using this approach, which makes me think I'm missing something ... Is this going to cause me problems as I grow my application?

I read a lot of people talking about having a repository per root entity - but if I identify root entities with some interface and restrict the generic methods to only allow classes implementing that interface, then aren't I achieving the same thing?

thanks in advance for any offerings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently using a mix of both generic repositories (`IRepository<T>`) and custom (`ICustomRepository`).  I do not expose `IQueryable` or `IQueryOver` from my repositories though.

Also I am only using my repositories as a query interface.  I do all of my saving, updating, deleting through the Session (unit of work) object that I'm injecting into my repository.  This allows me to do transactions across different repositories.

I've found that I definitely cannot do everything from a generic repository but they are definitely useful in a number of cases.

To answer your question though I do not think it's a bad idea to have a single generic repository if you can get by with it.  In my implementation this would not work but if it works for you then that's great.  I think it comes down to what works best for you.  I don't think you will ever find a solution out there that works perfectly for your situation.   I've found hybrid solutions work best for me.

Comment: I use this method, but I do expose IQueryOver and even Session from my repository and this gives me the ability to allow NHibernate into my controlllers or helper classes. Works well for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar in my projects.  One drawback is that you'll have to be careful you don't create a select n+1 bug.  I got around it by passing a separate list of properties to eagerly fetch.

The main argument you'll hear against wrapping your ORM like this is that it's a leaky abstraction.  You'll still have to code around some the "gotchas" like select n+1 and you don't get to take full advantage of things like NH's caching support (at least not without extra code).

Here's a [good thread](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) on the pros and cons of this approach on Ayende's blog.  He's more or less opposed to the pattern, but there are a few counter arguments too.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented such kind of repository for NHibernate. You can see example [here](http://slynetblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/in-spite-of-common-now-approach-of.html).

In that implementation you are able to do eager loading and fetching. The pitfall is that with NH  you will often need to be able to use QueryOver or Criteria API to access data (unfortunately LINQ provider is still far from being perfect). And with such an abstraction it could be a problem leading to leaky abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

I have actually moved away from repository pattern and creating a unit of work interfaces - I find it limiting.

Unless you anticipate a change in the datastore i.e. going from DB to textfile or XML - which has never been the case for me, you are best off using ISession. You are trying to abstract your data access and this is exactly what NHibernate does. Using repository limits really cool features like Fetch(), FetchMany() futures etc. ISession is your unit of work.

Embrace NHibernate and use the ISession directly!

Comment: I find that the repository pattern makes it a lot easier to unit test my code that uses the repositories.

Comment: @ColeW - I'm using sqlite in memory database with my tests. It is fast and I don't need to create additional layer on top of ISession. I used to use IRepository but once I switched to ISession it has been lot easier to work with NHibernate.

Comment: @ToniParviainen I'm talking about unit tests.  What you are talking about are integration tests.

Comment: @ColeW. I assume you are talking about mocking your db access and use repository to do this? I always work directly with data, be it SQL Lite or SQL. I find the additional complexity doesn't offer and merit and time is always an issue with clients, damn clients and their deliverables...

Comment: @Chev I agree with what your saying.  I have a mix of both kinds of tests.  In my situation I found it to be more complex to try and do all integration tests.

Comment: The main advantage of the Repository pattern is that the rest of the application doesn't care whether you're using NH, EF or cloud storage. Also the repository receives and sends back Domain objects and not persistence objects. NH models the persistence model and NOT the domain model. If both happen to be the same, because of a trivial domain, I'd still use the repository since I don't like having persistence implementation details mixing with the rest of the application. In fact the repository should be designed before even deciding what/if ORM to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this approach successfully on a few projects. It gets burdensome passing in many `IRepository<T>` to my Service layers for each BaseEntity, but it works. One thing I would change is put the `where T :` on the interface rather than the methods

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
```